# Fail to install Boost by installation prefix

Tags: c++, boost

After downloading the latest version of C++ boost from official site, I ran with root privileges: 
 `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local` and next `./b2 --prefix=/usr/local` (according to the tutorial). But when it was built, I saw this message:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/username/Downloads/boost_1_65_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/username/Downloads/boost_1_65_0/stage/lib
```

, so libraries and headers was installed into current directory, and prefix was ignored. Running without prefix (/usr/local is default value) leads to the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `./b2 install --prefix=PREFIX`

Comment: @perencia my inattention:( it works, thanks